# In NestJS and passport, how do I create an endpoint that accepts a valid or invalid JWT?

Tags: jwt, controller, nestjs, passport-jwt

I'm using NestJS 10 with passport-jwt.  I have a controller method in which the user can access whether or not they include a valid JWT in the Authorization header.  If they include a JWT, I would like to know who the user is

```
  @UseGuards(OptionalAccessTokenGuard)
  @Post('paymentIntent')
  createPaymentIntent(
    @Req() req: Request,
    @Body() createOrderDto: CreateOrderDto,
  ): Promise<PaymentIntent> {
    const userId = req?.user['sub'];
    return this.ordersService.createPaymentIntent(userId, createOrderDto);
  }
```

The guard I have is defined as such

```
@Injectable()
export class OptionalAccessTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
    await super.canActivate(context);
    return true;
  }
}
```

THe problem is, if the user submits an invalid JWT (it has expired or there is some other problem), this method returns a 401.  How can I adjust the guard or method such that submitting an invalid or expired JWT will still allow the method to proceed, only that the user ID is not obtained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `try/catch` around the `super.canActivate`, so that if it throws an error it can still return true